# Find a sum of series with complex-analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

How to calculate this sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nz)}{n!}$$

Comment: $\sin(nz) = (e^{inz}-e^{-inz})/(2i)$.  Your series becomes a sum of two exponential functions.

Comment: It’s task from my teacher. And we haven’t done such exercises yet

Comment: And what to do with these two sums. I’ll have two sums which are similar to Taylor representation of exponents

Comment: Entering it into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+sin%28n*x%29%2Fn%21%2C+n+from+0+to+inf) gives you an answer. You can try to reverse engineer a solution from there.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(nz)}{n!} \\
& \text{(starting with $n=0$ does not change the} \\
& \phantom{(}\text{sum but affects the way we proceed below.)} \\ {} \\
= {} & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Im}(e^{nz})}{n!} = \operatorname{Im} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(e^z)^n}{n!} \right) = \operatorname{Im} \left( e^{e^z} \right) \\ {} \\
= {} & \operatorname{Im} \left( e^{|z|(\cos(\arg(z)) + i\sin(\arg(z)))} \right) \\ {} \\
= {} & \operatorname{Im} \left( e^{|z|\cos(\arg(z))} \big( \cos(\sin(\arg(z))) + i\sin(\sin(\arg(z))) \big) \right) 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I was going to post this $\quad \uparrow\quad$, maybe followed by another line or two, but the question got closed. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}=e^z$ and $\displaystyle \sin(nz)=\frac{e^{inz}-e^{-inz}}{2i}$. So the sum is 
$$\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\left(e^{iz}\right)^n}{n!}
-\frac{\left(e^{-iz}\right)^n}{n!}\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{e^{iz}}-e^{e^{-iz}}\right)$$
and after using $e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ this simplifies to $e^{\cos(z)}\sin(\sin(z))$